# Limit background data on WiFi (Windows 8)

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking

I often use tethering to connect my Win8 laptop to the internet through my smartphone, but I'm worried of the amount of background data transferred for software updates. Is it possible to limit the background data, even if Windows reports the connection as WiFi?

Comment: The question is similar, but the answer doesn't actually give any instructions on how to set it up, it only points out what you *can't* do.

Comment: Still the same question (IMO).  But they, takes more than my vote to close it.

Comment: Would it be better if I remove this question and copy my answer to the other question?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to limit the background data on any connection in Windows 8. Here's how to do it:

1. Locate and click the bars icon in the lower right corner of your screen
   [image: Network settings]
2. Locate your current connection in the list of available networks.
3. Right click the name of your connection and select "Set as metered connection"
   [image: Wireless networks right-click menu]
4. If background data usage is no longer an issue, repeat the process and select "Set as non-metered connection".